# Why is Set marked by the compiler as "not a known variable in this context"?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

This is my code;

```
import java.util.*;  

  class State extends HashMap<Character, State>{

    boolean isFinal;

    State () {
        isFinal = false;
        }

    }

      class Automaton{
        private Set<State> allStates;
        private Set<State> finalStates;
        private State initialState;
        private State currentState;
        private Set<Character> alphabet;


        Automaton() {


            allStates = new Set<State>();
        }

 }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
allStates = new Set<State>();
```

Set is an interface.  So maybe you mean HashSet?

Comment: Makes sense, but I get the compiler message "Cannot instantiate the type Set<State>" which makes a lot more sense to me. Can someone explain the message dmindreader got and why we didn't get the same one?

Comment: Probably impossible to say given the information provided.  Without the specific error and more of the relevant code (I assume this has been abbreviated) I can't say.  I would also have expected the error you are seeing.

Comment: I suggest the error message is misquoted. Googling for “not a known variable in this context” gets this page...